# Adding an extra figure in a working document seems to break it "! Output loop---100 consecutive dead cycles."

Tags: floats, pdftex

I have a perfectly working document which already has 89 figures. Trying to add another one seems to break it. Just for testing, the new figure I am adding is a copy of the last one, only changing the label:

```
\begin{figure}[!htpb]
    \begin{center}
        \includegraphics[width=0.99\linewidth]{results/cage_esp/ed_0.05_modelEDESP.png}
        \caption{My caption. $ed\_factor = 0.05$}
        \label{fig:cageespEDESP0.05}
    \end{center}
\end{figure}
```

This produces a PDF, but it doesnt look good, with different margins at different parts, and titles which are justified. It also returns the following very low error:

```
! Output loop---100 consecutive dead cycles.
\newpage ...prevdepth \fi \fi \vfil \penalty -\@M 
                                                  
l.1473 \end{document}
                     
I've concluded that your \output is awry; it never does a
\shipout, so I'm shipping \box255 out myself. Next time
increase \maxdeadcycles if you want me to be more patient!

[58
! Incomplete \iffalse; all text was ignored after line 1473.
<inserted text> 
                \fi 
l.1473 \end{document}
                     
A forbidden control sequence occurred in skipped text.
This kind of error happens when you say `\if...' and forget
the matching `\fi'. I've inserted a `\fi'; this might work.

Runaway text?
\@writefile{toc}{\protect \gdef {}\vskip \z@ plus.2\p@ {\leftskip 3.8\ETC.
! Forbidden control sequence found while scanning text of \write.
<inserted text> 
                }
l.1473 \end{document}
                     
I suspect you have forgotten a `}', causing me
to read past where you wanted me to stop.
I'll try to recover; but if the error is serious,
you'd better type `E' or `X' now and fix your file.

Runaway text?
\@writefile{toc}{\protect \gdef {}\vskip \z@ plus.2\p@ {\leftskip 3.8\ETC.
! Forbidden control sequence found while scanning text of \write.
<inserted text> 
                }
l.1473 \end{document}
                     
I suspect you have forgotten a `}', causing me
to read past where you wanted me to stop.
I'll try to recover; but if the error is serious,
you'd better type `E' or `X' now and fix your file.

Runaway text?
\@writefile{toc}{\protect \gdef {}\vskip \z@ plus.2\p@ {\leftskip 3.8\ETC.
! Forbidden control sequence found while scanning text of \write.
<inserted text> 
                }
l.1473 \end{document}
                     
I suspect you have forgotten a `}', causing me
to read past where you wanted me to stop.
I'll try to recover; but if the error is serious,
you'd better type `E' or `X' now and fix your file.

! Incomplete \iffalse; all text was ignored after line 1473.
<inserted text> 
                \fi 
l.1473 \end{document}
                     
A forbidden control sequence occurred in skipped text.
This kind of error happens when you say `\if...' and forget
the matching `\fi'. I've inserted a `\fi'; this might work.

Runaway text?
\@writefile{toc}{\protect \gdef {}\vskip \z@ plus.2\p@ {\leftskip 3.8\ETC.
! Forbidden control sequence found while scanning text of \write.
<inserted text> 
                }
l.1473 \end{document}
                     
I suspect you have forgotten a `}', causing me
to read past where you wanted me to stop.
I'll try to recover; but if the error is serious,
you'd better type `E' or `X' now and fix your file.

Runaway text?
\@writefile{toc}{\protect \gdef {}\vskip \z@ plus.2\p@ {\leftskip 3.8\ETC.
! Forbidden control sequence found while scanning text of \write.
<inserted text> 
                }
l.1473 \end{document}
                     
I suspect you have forgotten a `}', causing me
to read past where you wanted me to stop.
I'll try to recover; but if the error is serious,
you'd better type `E' or `X' now and fix your file.

Runaway text?
\@writefile{toc}{\protect \gdef {}\vskip \z@ plus.2\p@ {\leftskip 3.8\ETC.
! Forbidden control sequence found while scanning text of \write.
<inserted text> 
                }
l.1473 \end{document}
                     
I suspect you have forgotten a `}', causing me
to read past where you wanted me to stop.
I'll try to recover; but if the error is serious,
you'd better type `E' or `X' now and fix your file.

! Incomplete \iffalse; all text was ignored after line 1473.
<inserted text> 
                \fi 
l.1473 \end{document}
                     
A forbidden control sequence occurred in skipped text.
This kind of error happens when you say `\if...' and forget
the matching `\fi'. I've inserted a `\fi'; this might work.

Runaway text?
\@writefile{toc}{\protect \gdef {}\vskip \z@ plus.2\p@ {\leftskip 3.8\ETC.
! Forbidden control sequence found while scanning text of \write.
<inserted text> 
                }
l.1473 \end{document}
                     
I suspect you have forgotten a `}', causing me
to read past where you wanted me to stop.
I'll try to recover; but if the error is serious,
you'd better type `E' or `X' now and fix your file.

Runaway text?
\@writefile{toc}{\protect \gdef {}\vskip \z@ plus.2\p@ {\leftskip 3.8\ETC.
! Forbidden control sequence found while scanning text of \write.
<inserted text> 
                }
l.1473 \end{document}
                     
I suspect you have forgotten a `}', causing me
to read past where you wanted me to stop.
I'll try to recover; but if the error is serious,
you'd better type `E' or `X' now and fix your file.

Runaway text?
\@writefile{toc}{\protect \gdef {}\vskip \z@ plus.2\p@ {\leftskip 3.8\ETC.
! Forbidden control sequence found while scanning text of \write.
<inserted text> 
                }
l.1473 \end{document}
                     
I suspect you have forgotten a `}', causing me
to read past where you wanted me to stop.
I'll try to recover; but if the error is serious,
you'd better type `E' or `X' now and fix your file.

! Incomplete \iffalse; all text was ignored after line 1473.
<inserted text> 
                \fi 
l.1473 \end{document}
                     
A forbidden control sequence occurred in skipped text.
This kind of error happens when you say `\if...' and forget
the matching `\fi'. I've inserted a `\fi'; this might work.

Runaway text?
\@writefile{toc}{\protect \gdef {}\vskip \z@ plus.2\p@ {\leftskip 3.8\ETC.
! Forbidden control sequence found while scanning text of \write.
<inserted text> 
                }
l.1473 \end{document}
                     
I suspect you have forgotten a `}', causing me
to read past where you wanted me to stop.
I'll try to recover; but if the error is serious,
you'd better type `E' or `X' now and fix your file.

Runaway text?
\@writefile{toc}{\protect \gdef {}\vskip \z@ plus.2\p@ {\leftskip 3.8\ETC.
! Forbidden control sequence found while scanning text of \write.
<inserted text> 
                }
l.1473 \end{document}
                     
I suspect you have forgotten a `}', causing me
to read past where you wanted me to stop.
I'll try to recover; but if the error is serious,
you'd better type `E' or `X' now and fix your file.

Runaway text?
\@writefile{toc}{\protect \gdef {}\vskip \z@ plus.2\p@ {\leftskip 3.8\ETC.
! Forbidden control sequence found while scanning text of \write.
<inserted text> 
                }
l.1473 \end{document}
                     
I suspect you have forgotten a `}', causing me
to read past where you wanted me to stop.
I'll try to recover; but if the error is serious,
you'd better type `E' or `X' now and fix your file.

! Incomplete \iffalse; all text was ignored after line 1473.
<inserted text> 
                \fi 
l.1473 \end{document}
                     
A forbidden control sequence occurred in skipped text.
This kind of error happens when you say `\if...' and forget
the matching `\fi'. I've inserted a `\fi'; this might work.

Runaway text?
\@writefile{toc}{\protect \gdef {}\vskip \z@ plus.2\p@ {\leftskip 3.8\ETC.
! Forbidden control sequence found while scanning text of \write.
<inserted text> 
                }
l.1473 \end{document}
                     
I suspect you have forgotten a `}', causing me
to read past where you wanted me to stop.
I'll try to recover; but if the error is serious,
you'd better type `E' or `X' now and fix your file.

Runaway text?
\@writefile{toc}{\protect \gdef {}\vskip \z@ plus.2\p@ {\leftskip 3.8\ETC.
! Forbidden control sequence found while scanning text of \write.
<inserted text> 
                }
l.1473 \end{document}
                     
I suspect you have forgotten a `}', causing me
to read past where you wanted me to stop.
I'll try to recover; but if the error is serious,
you'd better type `E' or `X' now and fix your file.

Runaway text?
\@writefile{toc}{\protect \gdef {}\vskip \z@ plus.2\p@ {\leftskip 3.8\ETC.
! Forbidden control sequence found while scanning text of \write.
<inserted text> 
                }
l.1473 \end{document}
                     
I suspect you have forgotten a `}', causing me
to read past where you wanted me to stop.
I'll try to recover; but if the error is serious,
you'd better type `E' or `X' now and fix your file.

! Incomplete \iffalse; all text was ignored after line 1473.
<inserted text> 
                \fi 
l.1473 \end{document}
                     
A forbidden control sequence occurred in skipped text.
This kind of error happens when you say `\if...' and forget
the matching `\fi'. I've inserted a `\fi'; this might work.

Runaway text?
\@writefile{toc}{\protect \gdef {}\vskip \z@ plus.2\p@ {\leftskip 3.8\ETC.
! Forbidden control sequence found while scanning text of \write.
<inserted text> 
                }
l.1473 \end{document}
                     
I suspect you have forgotten a `}', causing me
to read past where you wanted me to stop.
I'll try to recover; but if the error is serious,
you'd better type `E' or `X' now and fix your file.

Runaway text?
\@writefile{toc}{\protect \gdef {}\vskip \z@ plus.2\p@ {\leftskip 3.8\ETC.
! Forbidden control sequence found while scanning text of \write.
<inserted text> 
                }
l.1473 \end{document}
                     
I suspect you have forgotten a `}', causing me
to read past where you wanted me to stop.
I'll try to recover; but if the error is serious,
you'd better type `E' or `X' now and fix your file.

Runaway text?
\@writefile{toc}{\protect \gdef {}\vskip \z@ plus.2\p@ {\leftskip 3.8\ETC.
! Forbidden control sequence found while scanning text of \write.
<inserted text> 
                }
l.1473 \end{document}
                     
I suspect you have forgotten a `}', causing me
to read past where you wanted me to stop.
I'll try to recover; but if the error is serious,
you'd better type `E' or `X' now and fix your file.

! Undefined control sequence.
\GenericError  ...                                
                                                    #4  \errhelp \@err@     ...
l.1473 \end{document}
                     
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
\GenericError  ...                                
                                                  \let \@err@               ...
l.1473 \end{document}
                     
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
\GenericError  ...                                
                                                  \@empty \def \MessageBreak...
l.1473 \end{document}
                     
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Use of \@item doesn't match its definition.
\@ifnextchar ...eserved@d =#1\def \reserved@a {#2}
                                                  \def \reserved@b {#3}\futu...
l.1473 \end{document}
                     
If you say, e.g., `\def\a1{...}', then you must always
put `1' after `\a', since control sequence names are
made up of letters only. The macro here has not been
followed by the required stuff, so I'm ignoring it.

Runaway text?
\@writefile{toc}{\protect \gdef {}\protect \begingroup \immediate \write \ETC.
! Forbidden control sequence found while scanning text of \write.
<inserted text> 
                }
l.1473 \end{document}
                     
I suspect you have forgotten a `}', causing me
to read past where you wanted me to stop.
I'll try to recover; but if the error is serious,
you'd better type `E' or `X' now and fix your file.

Runaway text?
\@writefile{toc}{\protect \gdef {}\protect \begingroup \immediate \write \ETC.
! Forbidden control sequence found while scanning text of \write.
<inserted text> 
                }
l.1473 \end{document}
                     
I suspect you have forgotten a `}', causing me
to read past where you wanted me to stop.
I'll try to recover; but if the error is serious,
you'd better type `E' or `X' now and fix your file.

Runaway text?
\@writefile{toc}{\protect \gdef {}\protect \begingroup \immediate \write \ETC.
! Forbidden control sequence found while scanning text of \write.
<inserted text> 
                }
l.1473 \end{document}
                     
I suspect you have forgotten a `}', causing me
to read past where you wanted me to stop.
I'll try to recover; but if the error is serious,
you'd better type `E' or `X' now and fix your file.

Runaway text?
\@writefile{toc}{\protect \gdef {}\protect \begingroup \immediate \write \ETC.
! Forbidden control sequence found while scanning text of \write.
<inserted text> 
                }
l.1473 \end{document}
                     
I suspect you have forgotten a `}', causing me
to read past where you wanted me to stop.
I'll try to recover; but if the error is serious,
you'd better type `E' or `X' now and fix your file.

Runaway text?
\@writefile{toc}{\protect \gdef {}\protect \begingroup \immediate \write \ETC.
! Forbidden control sequence found while scanning text of \write.
<inserted text> 
                }
l.1473 \end{document}
                     
I suspect you have forgotten a `}', causing me
to read past where you wanted me to stop.
I'll try to recover; but if the error is serious,
you'd better type `E' or `X' now and fix your file.

Runaway text?
\@writefile{toc}{\protect \gdef {}\protect \begingroup \immediate \write \ETC.
! Forbidden control sequence found while scanning text of \write.
<inserted text> 
                }
l.1473 \end{document}
                     
I suspect you have forgotten a `}', causing me
to read past where you wanted me to stop.
I'll try to recover; but if the error is serious,
you'd better type `E' or `X' now and fix your file.

] [58 <./results/size1.png (PNG copy)>] [59 <./results/polar_max.png (PNG copy)
>] [60 <./results/polar_min.png (PNG copy)>] [61 <./results/hgpolar_opt1.png (P
NG copy)>] [62 <./results/hgpolar_opt2.png (PNG copy)>] [63 <./results/hgpolar_
opt3.png (PNG copy)>] [64 <./results/hgpolar_opt4.png (PNG copy)>] [65 <./resul
ts/CB6_esp/ed_0.0_model2.png (PNG copy)> <./results/CB6_esp/ed_0.001_model2.png
 (PNG copy)>] [66 <./results/CB6_esp/ed_0.05_model2.png (PNG copy)> <./results/
CB6_esp/ed_0.1_model2.png (PNG copy)>] [67 <./results/CB6_esp/ed_0.2_model2.png
 (PNG copy)> <./results/CB6_esp/ed_0.3_model2.png (PNG copy)>] [68 <./results/C
B6_esp/ed_0.5_model2.png (PNG copy)> <./results/CB6_esp/ed_0.7_model2.png (PNG 
copy)>] [69 <./results/CB6_esp/ed_0.8_model2.png (PNG copy)> <./results/CB6_esp
/ed_0.9_model2.png (PNG copy)>] [70 <./results/CB6_esp/ed_0.95_model2.png (PNG 
copy)> <./results/CB6_esp/ed_0.999_model2.png (PNG copy)>] [71 <./results/CB6_e
sp/ed_1.0_model2.png (PNG copy)> <./results/CB6_esp/ed_0.0_modelEDESP.png (PNG 
copy)>] [72 <./results/CB6_esp/ed_0.001_modelEDESP.png (PNG copy)> <./results/C
B6_esp/ed_0.05_modelEDESP.png (PNG copy)>] [73 <./results/CB6_esp/ed_0.1_modelE
DESP.png (PNG copy)> <./results/CB6_esp/ed_0.2_modelEDESP.png (PNG copy)>]
[74 <./results/CB6_esp/ed_0.3_modelEDESP.png (PNG copy)> <./results/CB6_esp/ed_
0.5_modelEDESP.png (PNG copy)>] [75 <./results/CB6_esp/ed_0.7_modelEDESP.png (P
NG copy)> <./results/CB6_esp/ed_0.8_modelEDESP.png (PNG copy)>] [76 <./results/
CB6_esp/ed_0.9_modelEDESP.png (PNG copy)> <./results/CB6_esp/ed_0.95_modelEDESP
.png (PNG copy)>] [77 <./results/CB6_esp/ed_0.999_modelEDESP.png (PNG copy)> <.
/results/CB6_esp/ed_1.0_modelEDESP.png (PNG copy)>] [78 <./results/optcage1.png
 (PNG copy)>] [79 <./results/cage_esp/ed_0.0_model1.png (PNG copy)>] [80 <./res
ults/cage_esp/ed_0.001_model1.png (PNG copy)>] [81 <./results/cage_esp/ed_0.05_
model1.png (PNG copy)>] [82 <./results/cage_esp/ed_0.1_model1.png (PNG copy)>]
[83 <./results/cage_esp/ed_0.2_model1.png (PNG copy)>] [84 <./results/cage_esp/
ed_0.3_model1.png (PNG copy)>] [85 <./results/cage_esp/ed_0.5_model1.png (PNG c
opy)>] [86 <./results/cage_esp/ed_0.7_model1.png (PNG copy)>] [87 <./results/ca
ge_esp/ed_0.8_model1.png (PNG copy)>] [88 <./results/cage_esp/ed_0.9_model1.png
 (PNG copy)>] [89 <./results/cage_esp/ed_0.95_model1.png (PNG copy)>] [90 <./re
sults/cage_esp/ed_0.999_model1.png (PNG copy)>] [91 <./results/cage_esp/ed_1.0_
model1.png (PNG copy)>] [92 <./results/cage_esp/ed_0.0_modelEDESP.png (PNG copy
)>] [93 <./results/cage_esp/ed_0.001_modelEDESP.png (PNG copy)>] [94 <./results
/cage_esp/ed_0.05_modelEDESP.png (PNG copy)>] (./si.aux
! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
l.289 ...l{\let \protected@file@percent }} } } } }
                                                   }
I've deleted a group-closing symbol because it seems to be
spurious, as in `$x}$'. But perhaps the } is legitimate and
you forgot something else, as in `\hbox{$x}'. In such cases
the way to recover is to insert both the forgotten and the
deleted material, e.g., by typing `I$}'.

! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
l.289 ...\let \protected@file@percent }} } } } } }
                                                  
I've deleted a group-closing symbol because it seems to be
spurious, as in `$x}$'. But perhaps the } is legitimate and
you forgot something else, as in `\hbox{$x}'. In such cases
the way to recover is to insert both the forgotten and the
deleted material, e.g., by typing `I$}'.

)

LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.


LaTeX Warning: Label(s) may have changed. Rerun to get cross-references right.

 )
(\end occurred when \ifvmode on line 1473 was incomplete)
(\end occurred when \ifnum on line 1473 was incomplete)
(\end occurred when \ifnum on line 1473 was incomplete)
(\end occurred when \ifnum on line 1473 was incomplete)
(\end occurred when \ifnum on line 1473 was incomplete)
(\end occurred when \ifnum on line 1473 was incomplete)
(\end occurred when \ifnum on line 1473 was incomplete)
(\end occurred when \ifnum on line 1473 was incomplete) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 7522 strings out of 478238
 140444 string characters out of 5850456
 459348 words of memory out of 5000000
 25581 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 486933 words of font info for 75 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 60i,11n,67p,982b,292s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
{/usr/share/texmf-dist/f
onts/enc/dvips/cm-super/cm-super-ts1.enc}{/usr/share/texmf-dist/fonts/enc/dvips
/cm-super/cm-super-t1.enc}</usr/share/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm
/cmmi12.pfb></usr/share/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr12.pfb></u
sr/share/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmsy10.pfb></usr/share/texmf
-dist/fonts/type1/public/cm-super/sfbx1200.pfb></usr/share/texmf-dist/fonts/typ
e1/public/cm-super/sfbx1440.pfb></usr/share/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/cm-su
per/sfbx1728.pfb></usr/share/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/cm-super/sfrm0700.pf
b></usr/share/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/cm-super/sfrm1000.pfb></usr/share/t
exmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/cm-super/sfrm1200.pfb></usr/share/texmf-dist/fonts
/type1/public/cm-super/sfrm1440.pfb></usr/share/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/c
m-super/sfrm2074.pfb></usr/share/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/cm-super/sftt120
0.pfb>
Output written on si.pdf (95 pages, 16720246 bytes).
PDF statistics:
 508 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 254 compressed objects within 3 object streams
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 451 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

I have no idea how to fix it, since the new figure I am adding is exactly the same as the previous one.

Comment: LaTeX is having trouble placing your floats. An easy fix could be a `\clearpage` after those which are quite big.

Comment: is that really the _first_ error? Surprising but not impossible. There is always the option of doing what the error message suggests and put `\maxdeadcycles =200` in your preamble.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle this with also increasing the number of floats seemed to fix it.

I wonder why it is struggling placing the floats.